# How Can I Use Twitter Bootstrap in my Existing Web application?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I develop a web using 
my own StyleSheets.. now what's an easy way to add twitter bootstrap in it?

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap is a collection of style sheets and JS scripts that you can simply plugin to your website. Its implementation really depends on what features you want to use for your website. If you want to use the styleshees and re-write your website DOM structure to be responsive OR grid based, then you should include the CSS files, find the methodology under [scaffolding](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html).

You can also use the modals, sliders available within Bootstrap by including the bootstrap.js file. Find instructions under the [Javascript Section.](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html).

Additionally, you should look at their [examples](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/getting-started.html#examples).

Comment: Yeah, but what if you already have a design based on some factory / browsers' defaults and Bootstrap ruins it reassigning defaults. Can you forbid it do fiddle with defaults and make it affect only it's own styles?

Comment: Well, you can always build bootstrap from less/sass and omit what you don't want. Also, this might sound hacky but, use the cascading nature of css and place bootstrap before your existing structure. This way your defaults overwrite bootstraps.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at [the examples](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples.html) they provide.